# What SNMP MIB browser should I use?

Tags: snmp

What SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) [MIB (Management Information Base) browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management_information_base#MIB_browsers) should I use to interactively discover/explore/work with MIBs?

Possible choices:

- [SnmpB](https://sourceforge.net/projects/snmpb/)
- [mbrowse](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mbrowse/)
- (last contribution 2013: [BlackOwl](https://sourceforge.net/projects/blackowl/))
- [SMI-Mib Browser](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mibview/)
- [MBJ](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mbj/)
- /last contribution 2013: [JManager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/snmpjmanager/))
- (just device querying, no v3 support, despite of that seems: quite usable: [qtmib](http://qtmib.sourceforge.net/))
- (not free, no Linux support: [NetDecision MIB Browser](http://www.netmechanica.com/products/?prod_id=1009))
- (not free, no Linux support: [iReasoning MIB Browser](http://ireasoning.com/mibbrowser.shtml))
- [LoriotPro SNMP Manager](https://snmp-manager.com/)
- [spectacular](https://github.com/tenderlove/spectacular)
- (unmaintained: [Outlets](https://github.com/rashidkpc/Outlets))
- (not visual, cli only: [snob](https://github.com/lebogan/snob) (`yasb` rewrite in Crystal))
- (last contribution 2012: [SNMP-Browser](https://github.com/maryonmayor/SNMP-Browser))
- (last contribution 2014: [QMIBBrowser](https://github.com/luoyetx/QMIBBrowser))
- (not visual, cli only: [yasb](https://github.com/lebogan/yasb))

Requirements:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- cost: free
- SNMP protocols: v1, v2c and v3
- graphical browsing: needed
- search functionality: needed
- loading mib files from mib file databases
- import mib files from local file system
- snmp agent discovery: not needed
- snmp agent query: not needed
- trap events: not needed
- graph plotting: not needed

Comment: After first eval I think I'll try SnmpB, qtmib, snaob/yasb...

Comment: ... and yasb/snob as command line alternative.

Comment: When you have evaluated them all, please do post an answer and accept it, to help others in future. Thanks

Comment: @Mawg I wasn't really happy with the tools. Right now I'll stick to the [net-snmp](http://www.net-snmp.org/) tools (snmptranslate, etc.).

Comment: Then you can post that as an answer and accept it, which will help others who read this in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now I'll stick to the [net-snmp](http://www.net-snmp.org/) tools (snmptranslate, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

SnmpB is pretty good, here is a tutorial for it:
https://bestmonitoringtools.com/free-mib-browser-download-snmpb/

Even though you can browse MIB's online with Online MIB browser:
https://bestmonitoringtools.com/mibdb/mibdb_search.php

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, **iReasoning MIB Browser** is cross-platform, they have a free addition, and it comes with a lot of support MIBs that you may need to use the MIB you already have.

I'm using it with Linux Mint 21.1 to find the OIDs for specific registers on an APC/Schneider Electric UPS in a DC.